# Unable to Show or Hide my VSTO Excel Add-In

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, vsto, add-in

I have a ribbon called `Ribbon 1`

I want my ribbon to show only when a workbook is open. If only the excel application is running and no workbooks are open then I want to hide my ribbon tab. How can I do that?

This is what I tried but it is not hiding the ribbon

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private Sub Application_WorkbookOpen(ByVal doc As Excel.Workbook) Handles Application.WorkbookOpen
        If Application.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
            If Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Visible = False Then Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal doc As Excel.Workbook, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.WorkbookBeforeClose
        If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
            If Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Visible = True Then Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am not getting any error. It is simply not hiding it. I put a break point on `If Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Visible = True Then Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Visible = False`. The line executed but the tab didn't hide. I am having a brain freeze! Is this the right way to do what I want?

Comment: Can you try : `Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon.Ribbon1.Visible = false` ?

Comment: Also your test for equlity should be `==` and not `=`

Comment: Both will not work. 'Ribbon' is not a member of 'ThisRibbonCollection' and also `==` in vb.net will give error. `==` is C#. Yes, I did tag this question as C# becuase the basic logic to attempt this in both vb.net and c# will be same. :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not know it was different in vb.net. The code I proposed in my first comment works in a C# VSTO.

Comment: @Malick, In c#, `==` is used for comparision and `=` for assignment. In vb.net, `=` is used for both comparison as well as assignment. The compiler is smart enough to differentiate between the two. But ultimately both c# and vb.net compile down to same MSIL. So I'm pretty sure that code isn't working in c# either. But unexpected things keep happening in this world, so I'll give it a try in c# and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following equivalent code in c# works if the [ControlIdType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb546832(v=vs.120)) of the Ribbon is set to `Custom`, however it doesn't work if it is set to `Office` (I assume it is the case for you..). So it seems to me that you find a bug/limitation in the VSTO runtime: it is only possible to change the visibility if the tab is custom (i.e if it is on a new independent tab).

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WorkbookBeforeClose += Application_WorkbookBeforeClose;
        this.Application.WorkbookOpen += Application_WorkbookOpen;
    }

    private void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
    {
        if (this.Application.Workbooks.Count > 0) {
            if (Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.tab1.Visible == false) Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.tab1.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    private void Application_WorkbookBeforeClose(Excel.Workbook Wb, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (this.Application.Workbooks.Count == 1)
        {
            if (Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.tab1.Visible == true) Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.tab1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

*Edit: As properly shown in Siddharth Rout's answer, it is not a bug: to hide a tab with the `Office` configuration, we need to hide all the groups.*

Comment: Nicely explained :)

Answer (score 2):

As Malick mentioned, it depends on the `ControlIdType` of the Ribbon

[image]

If you change it to `Custom`, your original code posted in the question should work.

For `Office` you have to hide all the groups. Once all the Groups are hidden, the tab will automatically hide.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    '~~> Workbook Open
    Private Sub Application_WorkbookOpen(ByVal doc As Excel.Workbook) Handles Application.WorkbookOpen
        If Application.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ribbonGroup In Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Groups
                ribbonGroup.Visible = True
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    '~~> This is if the user presses CTRL + N for a new workbook
    Private Sub Application_WorkbookActivate(ByVal doc As Excel.Workbook) Handles Application.WorkbookActivate
        If Application.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ribbonGroup In Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Groups
                ribbonGroup.Visible = True
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    '~~> Before Close
    Private Sub Application_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal doc As Excel.Workbook, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.WorkbookBeforeClose
        If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
            If Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Visible = True Then
                For Each ribbonGroup In Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Tab1.Groups
                    ribbonGroup.Visible = False
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```